BTC.com Wallet recovery
I have a revovery sheet with Encrypted Primary Seed, Backup Seed, Encrypted Recovery Secret, BTC Wallet Public Keys, Password Encrypted Secret.
I tried to use https://recovery.blocktrail.com/ and it startet to search for funds. Then I get the message that there were no funds found. I also had to input my wallet password there otherwise it will throw an error.
It says that the first address of the wallet is "X" and on that address i can see that there are still btc on it. Wallet is from 2017 I tried to import it with electrum with several derivation paths but no luck yet. Do you think the backup seed can be used and does not need to be modified or something?
Best Regards

Maybe this is obvious, but why would you try to recover a "btc.com" wallet via "blocktrail.com"? Where those two the same company?
